# Visual Studio 2013 Excel Workbook

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, excel-2013

Visual Studio 2013 seems to offer the ability to create C# enabled workbooks (not add-ins or templates). I don't see anyone talking about it online. My guess is that it is used to create a workbook where C# replaces VBA. I'm wondering if I can use this to create a workbook that publishes live data from my C# program to the spreadsheet. I'm also wondering how to manually add a spreadsheet like this to a project.

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668197.aspx

Comment: ah, I didn't realize it was called a Document Level Customization. Is there any chance that I can do this, but in F# rather than C#?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh297098(v=vs.100).aspx